# How to refresh part of the JSP with another JSP using AJAX

Tags: jsp

I'm submitting form using JSP. Servlet  process the request and loads the another JSP as a result. Instead of loading another JSP i would like to refresh the same original JSP keeping form data as it is using AJAX. But AJAX replaces only text and XML. How to get JSP?

Comment: show code how you written?

Answer (score 0):

Use this script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
        var xmlHttp  
        function showState(str)
        {
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined")
            {
              xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            var url="include.jsp";
            url +="?count=" +str;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
            xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
        function stateChange()
        {   
            if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
            {   
                document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
            }   
        }
      </script>
```

include.jsp will be jsp page which you need to include in parent jsp page. all the processing you have in include.jsp will be added to page in which you are writing script.
Along with this, **divid** will be id of div tag in which you want to include the contents of include.jsp